# one link to multiple container anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to solve a problem I am having with my navigation links showing multiple content in different div containers.

I currently have 4 containers with overflow:hidden on one page. I have put content in each with anchors relating to 4 different navigation links. The problem I am having is when I click one of the navigation links only one of the divs moves its content to the related anchor and not all at once.

Example:

Navigation

```
    <div class="nav_link"><p><a href="#anchor2">WHAT WE DO</a></p></div>
    <div class="nav_space"></div>
    <div class="nav_link"><p><a href="#anchor3">OUR PHILOSOPHY</a></p></div>
    <div class="nav_space"></div>
    <div class="nav_link"><p><a href="#anchor4">THE PANTRY</a></p></div>
    <div class="nav_space"></div>
    <div class="nav_link"><p><a href="#anchor5">CONTACT</a></p></div>
```

Container 1 (works fine)

```
    <div class="identity"><a name="anchor1"></a><span class="ArialBol21Red">Gocek</span><span class="ArialBol14Red">Turkey</span></div>
    <div class="identity"><a name="anchor2"></a><span class="ArialBol14Red">What we do</span></div>
    <div class="identity"><a name="anchor3"></a><span class="ArialBol14Red">Our philosophy</span></div>
    <div class="identity"><a name="anchor4"></a><span class="ArialBol14Red">The pantry</span></div>
    <div class="identity"><a name="anchor5"></a><span class="ArialBol14Red">Contact</span></div>
```

Container 2 (Doesn't work)

```
    <div class="leftcontent_box"><a name="anchor2"></a>What we do</div>
    <div class="leftcontent_box"><a name="anchor3"></a>Our philosophy</div>
    <div class="leftcontent_box"><a name="anchor4"></a>The pantry</div>
    <div class="leftcontent_box"><a name="anchor5"></a>Contact</div>
```

I am guessing that it is finding the anchor in the first container and not bothering looking at the other containers for the same anchor.

Hope this makes some sense.

APPROACH 2 (Wrapping each category content in a relative class and then have the link make all of specific class come to top of container?)

```
    <div id="page_identifier_box">

    <div class="identity"><div class="anchor1"><span class="ArialBol21Red">Gocek</span><span class="ArialBol14Red">Turkey</span></div></div>
    <div class="identity"><div class="anchor2"></a><span class="ArialBol14Red">What we do</span></div></div>
    <div class="identity"><div class="anchor3"></a><span class="ArialBol14Red">Our philosophy</span></div></div>
    <div class="identity"><div class="anchor4"></a><span class="ArialBol14Red">The pantry</span></div></div>
    <div class="identity"><div class="anchor5"></a><span class="ArialBol14Red">Contact</span></div></div>

    </div>

    <div id="leftcontent">


    <div id="leftcontent_box"><div class="anchor1"><div id="leftcontent_main_photo"><img src="leftcontent_main_image.jpg"></div><div id="leftcontent_main_text"><span class="ArialReg12Black">Order fresh in season strawberries supplied from the local market for just £16.</span></div></div></div>

    <div class="leftcontent_box"><div class="anchor2">What we do</div></div>

    <div class="leftcontent_box"><div class="anchor3">Our philosophy</div></div>

    <div class="leftcontent_box"><div class="anchor4">The pantry</div></div>

    <div class="leftcontent_box"><div class="anchor5">Contact</div></div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the html specifications `id`s must be unique across your html document. If they are not, things will not work as expected. So fix your ids, make sure they're unique, and try again.

**Update**

I see what you mean now. The issue isn't with the uniqueness of the ids, but the anchor names instead. According to [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1) the anchor names also must be unique within a document.

Comment: True I didn't write that correctly. changed the non unique div id's (nav_link and nav_space) to div classes but it's not that.

Comment: Indeed I gathered that the anchor names might have to be unique but the problem here is that if you gave them different anchor names, how would you link to both anchors through one link (www.website.url#anchor3part1+anchor3part2 for example)

Comment: I would use javascript to display the correct items. Or do a normal page reload (without the anchors) and show only the requested information.

Comment: I have taken another look at this to see if I could approach the problem in a different way. I have come up with a different approach but still am not sure if this could work. If I split the 5 categories in to classes (.anchor1,.anchor2,.anchor3,.anchor4,.anchor5) and then rap each part in each container with it respective anchor class would it be possible to tell a link to pull by class name to top of each container.. does that make sense?